# Add custom capabilities to existing custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, capabilities

The only way I can find to associate post types with custom capabilities is during the register_post_type function.  I'm looking to add a capability for a certain role (my_role) for a post type that already exists (my_post_type).

I'm looking to allow front-end users to view my_post_types only as well as create them using a form on the front-end. How do I allow users of role my_role to edit only posts of type my_post_type that they have created?